# Defining a Map Between Two Chain Complexes

Tags: homological-algebra

I would like someone to check my reasoning here and, if my reasoning is correct, help me define a map to make a short exact sequence.

I am given a short exact sequence of chain complexes
$$
0\longrightarrow B\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} C\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} D\longrightarrow 0.
$$
Let $C_f$ be the cone on $f$, so $(C_f)_n=B_{n-1}\oplus C_n$.  And let $Cyl_g$ be the cylinder on $g$, so $(Cyl_g)_n=C_n\oplus C_{n-1}\oplus D_n$.  Then there is a chain map
$$
C_f\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} Cyl_g
$$
given by $\alpha(b,c)=(c,-f(b),0)$ where $c\in C_n$ and $b\in B_{n-1}$.  Since $f$ is injective, $\alpha$ is injective.  It seems to me that the cokernel of $\alpha$ should be $D[-1]\oplus D$, were $D[-1]$ is the shift of $D$.  So, I should get a short exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow C_f\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} Cyl_g\stackrel{\beta}{\longrightarrow} D[-1]\oplus D\longrightarrow 0.
$$
My problem is defining $\beta$.  I tried the obvious $\beta(c_1,c_2,d)=(g(c_2),d)$.  But, when I checked, that did not define a chain map.  Assuming my reasoning is correct, what should $\beta$ be?  Thanks.

EDIT: The differential on $Cyl_g$ is given by
$$
\partial(c_1,c_2,d)=(\partial c_1+c_2,-\partial c_2,\partial d -g(c_2)).
$$
Then 
$$
\beta(\partial(c_1,c_2,d))=(-\partial g(c_2),\partial d-g(c_2))
$$
and
$$
\partial(\beta(c_1,c_2,d))=(\partial g(c_2),\partial d).
$$

Comment: Why do you think the definition you gave of $\beta$ doesn't work?  It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @HughThomas I have edited the question to show my calculations.

Comment: $\alpha$ also doesn't define a chain map.  Something seems to be amiss with the given information.

Comment: @HughThomas The definition for the differential on $C_f$ is $$\partial(b,c)=(-\partial b,\partial c-f(b)).$$  Given that $g(f(b))=0$, $\alpha$ is a chain map by my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your choice of $\beta$ works.

However, the differential on $D_{n-1}\oplus D_n$ is given by $\partial(d_1,d_2)=(-\partial d_1, \partial d_2 -d_1)$.

Comment: Just so I know I have the right idea: The differential is what you say because we are viewing $D_{n-1}\oplus D_n$ as a quotient of the cylinder.  So, the differential is the one that is induced from the differential on the cylinder?

Comment: Yes.  I mean, you essentially had to choose $\beta$ as you did, and then that forces the differential on you.